# error: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

```
Edit:

 DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
 string _idCompany = Request["idCompany"];
        var newes = dc.GetNewsCompany(Int64.Parse(_idCompany));            
        string date = "";
        string newsHtml = "<center>"; 
        if(newes.GetEnumerator().MoveNext()){
            foreach (var item in newes)//say Error .......................
            {
               // date = calendar.GetDayOfMonth(item.DateSend) + "/" + calendar.GetMonth(item.DateSend) + "/" + calendar.GetYear(item.DateSend).ToString();
            //    newsHtml += "<li class='news-item'><a style='text-decoration:none' class=\"link\" onclick=\"$(\'#BodyNews\').text(\'" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Body).Trim() + "\');$(\'#BodyNews\').dialog({resizable:false});\"   href=\"#\" > " + item.Title.ToString() + "</a>&nbsp;" + date + "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;       </li>";

            }

            newsHtml += "</center>";
            }
            else
            {
               // var propertyCompany = dc.GetPropertyCompanyById(Int64.Parse(_idCompany));
           //     newsHtml += "<li class='news-item'><a style='text-decoration:none' class=\"link\" );$(\'#BodyNews\').dialog({resizable:false});\"   href=\"#\" > " + "!به صفحه شخصی شرکت " + propertyCompany.FirstOrDefault().NameCompany + " خوش آمدید " + "</a>&nbsp;" + date + "   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;       </li>";

            }
        return newsHtml;
```

say error:The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

how check `var` is empty or null with out enumerated;

Comment: Re the Edit: Yes, everything will give an Error after the Movenext. So remove the MoveNext.

Comment: if remove moveNext then newes.all() agian same error

Comment: Not if you use `newesList.All()` . Please read the answers carefully, we're now repeating ourselves.

Comment: how check that newes is null or empty

Comment: no then does not worked by newes because same error

Comment: Don't use `newes`. Use `newsList` for everything after the `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother with the `if` at all?

```
var newes = dc.GetNewsCompany(Int64.Parse(_idCompany));
//if (newes.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())//check is null or empty
var newesList = newes.ToList();
if (neweList.Count > 0) 
{
    ...
}
```

You can always check the `newesList.Count` property afterward.

Comment: Then you like some bad coding practice.

Comment: multi methods does not matter. news will be an `IEnumerable<X>` and ToList will be very cheap if it's empty. A `MoveNext()` will put your results in a state that is almost always unusable elsewhere.

Comment: var newesList=newes.ToList();newes.All();    say error agin: The query results cannot be enumerated more than once

Comment: Where does the newes.All() come from?  Make it newesList.All().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's available as a member in newes, but if it's an object and depending on what dc.GetNewsCompany returns you could check for null

```
if (news == null) return;
```

or if it returns an empty collection/array, just check the count/length:

```
if (news.Count == 0) return;
if (news.Length == 0) return;
```

Comment: no, if(news.count==0)return or ...;say error: cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Comment: `newes` will never be null. And `newes.Count()` will be almost as expensive as `ToList()` when there are (many) records.

Answer (score 0):

the error comes, because you are using .GetEnumerator() on newes and then using the newes again in a foreach Loop .. this causes the "double enumeration".

Generally avoid walking "such var"'s with a foreach, since the DataReader is locked the whole loop !. Means that you cannot use the same entitie in this loop.

Better `.ToList()` , you can the list.AsQuearable agian if you want to Linq on it

f.e. something like

```
var newes = dc.CompanyTable.Where(ln => ln.id.Equals(_idCompany));;
List<CompanyTable> newesList = newes.ToList();
```